# Is Zen Coding/Emmet available for Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, emmet

Zen Coding/Emmet seems to be perfect to build those tedious Android XML layouts. Is it available for Android in any way or on any text editors? If not, would it be possible to start coding it for one?

Comment: Since Zen Coding does not appear to have been updated in three years, I would assume that the project is dead.

Comment: Try android-Studio IDE. They have made android layout create simple and neat

Comment: @CommonsWare Oh, it seems to have been renamed to Emmet recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emmet is not tied to HTML and CSS. For XML syntax, it takes any expression and converts it to XML code so basically it supports Android XML layouts out-of-box. You can also add your own element aliases to increase productivity: http://docs.emmet.io/customization/snippets/

Comment: Thanks! I'll look at building something from it.